# Laravel Resources Setting Custom Headers

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

So I'm trying to set the cache-control header in my response inside my resource but it does not seem to work.  I always get "no-cache" in my cache-control header in my response.

I followed [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses) laravel guide and did the following:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class RouteResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'from' => $this->from,
            'to' => $this->to,
            'distance' => empty($this->distance) ? "" : $this->distance,
            'duration' => empty($this->duration) ? "" : $this->duration,
            'suspended' => (!empty($this->suspended_at))? true:false,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Customize the outgoing response for the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Response  $response
     * @return void
     */
    public function withResponse($request, $response)
    {
        $response->header('Cache-Control', 'max-age=3600');
    }
}
```

However that did not work as well.  I Was finally able to get the header to return by doing this:

```php
return response(RouteResource::collection($routes))->header('Cache-Control', 'max-age=3600');
```

But this feels wrong or more like a hack.  I want to know why it didn't work with my resource initially as described in the docs, how do I return my `cache-control` header in my response?

Comment: Could you add how you returned your resource before you solved it with `response(..)->header(..)`

Comment: ```RouteResource::collection($routes)``` like this.

Answer (score 0):

1.create the file \App\Http\Middleware\NoCache.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class NoCache  
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {
       $response = $next($request);

       $response->header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, must-revalidate');

       return $response;
    }
}
```

2.Open \App\Http\Kernel.php and add to $middleware if you want it on all

```
 \App\Http\Middleware\NoCache::class,
```

or define the key to pick and choose.

```
'nocache' => \App\Http\Middleware\NoCache::class,
```

Comment: I want cache, why would I create a no-cache middleware?